# How to implement vertical scrolling of a grid items within a grid in material ui?

Tags: css, reactjs, scroll, material-ui

How does one add vertical scrolling functionality to a grid container, such that its components can be vertically scrolled through if the height of the components exceeds some max?

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you're using the latest MUI, it can be as simple as adding `overflowY: 'scroll'` and setting a `maxHeight` via the `Grid` container's `sx` prop (or its parent element).  For example:

```
      <Grid
        sx={{ overflowY: "scroll", maxHeight: "250px" }}
        container
        spacing={2}
      >
        ...
      </Grid>
```

Working CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-5-scrollable-grid-gjxfq?file=/demo.js

Comment: JFYI dear reader, you can customize the scrollbar just like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71893788/8784518